# UIButton & UITextView Not Selectable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In one of my view controllers I have a text view and a simple button. However, I'm running into an issue where the text view and button are not selectable. When I tap the button, the action function does not go through (not even printing a line). Similarly, the text view does not take in any gestures nor is it editable when enabled.

Should have been an easy implementation but I am not sure what the issue is. I tried to play with the view controller alpha values to see if that was the issue, but no luck there.

```
import MessageUI
class ProfileVC: UsernameVC, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailButtonLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var attenDescrip: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func emailPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("email pressed")
        let mailCOmposevViewController = configureMailController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail(){
            self.present(mailCOmposevViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            showMailError()
        }
    }

    func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailCOmposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailCOmposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailCOmposerVC.setToRecipients(["first@gmail.com"])
        mailCOmposerVC.setSubject("Application")
        mailCOmposerVC.setMessageBody("app.", isHTML: false)
        return mailCOmposerVC
    }

    func showMailError() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send email", message: "Please set up your email account", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
        self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't call `configureMailController()` before checking `canSendMail()`. There's no point in creating and setting up `MFMailComposeViewController` if you can't send email.

Comment: Do you mean text view instead of scroll view?

Comment: Why do you comment out the call to `super.viewDidLoad` in your `viewDidLoad` method? That's bad.

Comment: @rmaddy yes text view. super.viewdidload is commented out because the class is a reference to UsernameVC. That is not the issue as it work fine I just can't toggle any buttons in that view controller.

Comment: If you override `viewDidLoad` you must call `super.viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @rmaddy no you don't. App is on the app store for months working fine.

Comment: Have you checked if the `userInteractionEnabled` is set to true for the current or underlying views?